# Standard Classification of Disease

Tags: human-biology, pathology

I am working on a project for health center. It involves the creation of a database of all diseases. Currently I want to classify disease on the base of their category based on international standard.
Did anyone know where i can find one, I did a lot of research but was only able to come across this which seem not very useful to me: [ICD](http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/icd.htm)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two I know of off the top of my head are

- [OMIM](http://www.omim.org/) : Online Mendelian Inheritance in Man. This is very good and very well organized but only deals with inheritable diseases, no infections etc.
- [Human disease ontology](http://disease-ontology.org/). From their webpage:

  > The Disease Ontology has been developed as a standardized ontology for human disease with the purpose of providing the biomedical community with consistent, reusable and sustainable descriptions of human disease terms, phenotype characteristics and related medical vocabulary disease concepts through collaborative efforts of researchers at Northwestern University, Center for Genetic Medicine and the University of Maryland School of Medicine, Institute for Genome Sciences.

The DO is probably perfect for your needs.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you're also interested in mental health issues, but the DSM ([Diagnostic and Statistical Manual of Mental Disorders](http://www.dsm5.org/about/Pages/Default.aspx)) is the standard typology for that subject area.

*edit*: I see that the Disease Ontology that @terdon lists also has mental health as a category.